# If we are using Factory Pattern should we hide products from user?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Let say I have an `AnimalFactory` class which produces `Dog, Cat` and `Fish`. 
Using the `AnimalFactory` makes things incredibly simpler and everything is fine.

My question is that Is there a rule or **good practice** that suggests us hide Dog, Cat and Fish from being used directly? I mean `Dog myDog = new Dog();` will be forbidden in the code.

If there is, how can we hide them properly?

Comment: Spring's dependency injection might be useful for doing that type of stuff.

Comment: Java - Assuming your factory and animal classes are in the same package adding [protected, no modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) modifiers to the animal constructors would inhibit anything outside the package from instantiating animals

Comment: The *reason* factory exists is to hide products from the user. It's a principle called information hiding which reduces dependencies on things that could change.

Comment: @Chrizt0f except some IDEs like eclipse will propose "fixing" the visibility of concrete animals as soon as someone tries to instantiate one.

Comment: @Chrizt0f maybe with java 9 and its module feature. There is also the \*.internal.\* package convention.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I'll have to check that out. Both solutions are j9+?

Comment: @Chrizt0f I think it was targeted for j8 but didn't make it. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your objects should be created only through the factory, you should try to avoid the possibility of someone skipping this rule.

In c#, if the consumers of Dog, Cat and Fish are on different assemblies, you can make the constructors internal, this way only the factory, which is implemented in the same assembly as your "animals" can create them.

I'm sure there's something similar in java.

Comment: In Java you can work with private constructors to avoid explicit construction. For your animal example you can use: `private Dog() {}`

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on whether the consumer needs to care about a Dog or Cat, or are they OK with just some Animal?

That is, if Animal.Speak() is fine, then just expose animals and leave the implementation details as unknown to the consumer. However, if there's something Dog-specific, like Dog.BarkAtMoon(), then you have to have insight to how it's used.

Additionally, you might like to rely on interfaces, such as IAnimal. Then you have class Dog : IAnimal, and your factory returns IAnimals. In this way consumers know *even less* about implementations and have only the interface.

Perhaps you will have

```
class AnimalFactory
{
  IAnimal GetAnimal(AnimalTypeEnum type) { ... return IAnimal type requested ... }
  Dog GetDog(string name) { ... just give me a dog named "name" (or IDog) ... }
}
```

Comment: So, both methods getDog and getAnimal are good examples of factory pattern, it is not a must to hide the object type, and what I mean is that in your getAnimal method you are "hiding" which type of animal (object) you will return, and in your getDog you are not, but both are still factory pattern

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers pointing out the interface facet, factory pattern is also useful if a complex object needs to be constructed in a certain way, and you want to enforce that requirement in one place, IE the factory.  In that case it's best to also secure any other means of constructing that object, as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Yes.  Please allow me to elaborate -

When we directly instantiate objects like `Dog myDog = new Dog();`  we code a dependency.

Now lets say, you wish to write a unit test case for your function where Dog is instantiated, you would no chance to replace the actual dog object with a mock  Dog object. Therefore, we stick to interfaces & providing the dependencies from outside.

If I want to enforce the use of Interface & prevent the use of `new` operator, I can make the  following set up -

1. Assembly for Interfaces - this will define `public interface IDog`
2. Assembly for Concrete Implementation - This is have `internal class Dog` & a `public class Factory` whose `Create`  function will return `IDog`
3. Assembly for Client - Here `Dog` will not be accessible, so the only way client create an instance of dog will be through factory which will return `IDog` 
   Something like this `IDog dog = factory.Create();`

I have kept the setup pretty simple just to convey my point

Answer (score 0):

Dependency inversion principle tells us that client classes should avoid depending on concrete implementations. Factory pattern facilitates this by shielding the client from the creation logic and client would be working with an interface rather than some concrete class. Making the constructor of concrete classes package local and not public could be one good way.